# How to integrate 3D Secure authentication in PayPal payment gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Good day to all. I'm currently integrating PayPal payment gateway (BackEnd) in one of my projects. This is my first time working in a payment gateway. I want to integrate 3D Secure authentication using Orders API of paypal. Can anyone enlighten me on the flow of using the API for integrating Paypal using 3D Secure authentication?

For example:
I have tested using POSTMAN the normal flow without the 3D Secure authentication. And the flow is like below.

1. I get the amount and currency from the Front-End.
2. I create the Access token using clientID and secret which I receive from the company DB.
3. Then I create an order using https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders API.
4. I get checkOut link from the response like https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5O190127TN364715T
5. I redirect the user to this link which redirects the user to the Paypal page to make the payment. After completing the payment I redirect the user to the success/failure URL which also consists token and payer ID.
6. Then I use https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<token/orderID>/capture to complete the payment.

Now I want to add the 3D Secure authentication to it. From the documentation of integrating 3D Secure, I found that I need to add the payment source inside it and add **SCA_ALWAYS** as the verification attribute in the Card object. But how can I get the payment source to provide in the body as a request?  (FYI I'm not supposed to use any libraries from PayPal as a company policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When redirecting to a PayPal checkout page such as `https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5O190127TN364715T` in your example (or for a better UX, *never redirecting away* and instead using an [in-context popup](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) that keeps your site loaded), there is no need to implement 3D Secure. PayPal will present any 3D secure flow if needed, which will depend on the buyer account and its country and the credit card used, and might only happen the first time the card is used.

---

Implementing 3D secure only applies to direct card integrations such as [Advanced Credit and Debit Cards (with or without hosted fields)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/add-capabilities/3d-secure/), or the [Braintree Gateway](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/overview).

Comment: So in this scenario, I don't have to add anything else? May I know is there a way to test if it's working by default or not?

Comment: If you aren't using advanced credit and debit cards/hosted fields or the braintree gateway, there is nothing to implement or test. PayPal has its own integration with card companies and takes care of everything. You won't even know if a card was used to pay, all you know is you received a completed PayPal payment.

Comment: Another question, when the checkout page is loaded, based on the browser's cache/cookies it shows the option. Like if I open it in an incognito page, it shows everything like user can pay with Credit Card or Paypal account if have any but if I open it using another tab where I logged in paypal in previous transaction it doesn't show any credit card option even though I hard coaded the `landing page` to be `BILLING`. Is there any way to fix that so that everytime the `BILLING` page will be shown while redirecting to checkout link?Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't. The behavior of the PayPal page will always depend on cookies in that fashion. But if you want to always show a black "Debit or Credit Card" option, use the in-context flow

Comment: Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls  These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). When a capture response is successful, store the successful payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) before sending your return JSON

Comment: Pair your 2 routes with the in-context approval flow.. https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Does we need to add code for 3D on default magento 2 PayPal module.?